# Retrieving string between html tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have managed to retrieve the html content of a web page via jQuery and ajax.
Now I want to find the value between the h1 tags and display it.
How can I do it in jQuery?

```
$.get(link, function(res){
    //get link content
    var temp_content = res.responseText;
}
```

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( temp_content ).find( 'h1' ).text()
```

That should do it.  You are creating a jQuery object, finding the H1, and then getting its text.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find where in the returned string you have `<h1></h1>` and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get anything between `<h1></h1>`.

Note that if this webpage is on another domain you have cross-site scripting issues to deal with.  If it is on the same domain you should be fine.

```
$.get(link, function(res){
    //get link content
    var temp_content = res.responseText;
    $(temp_content).find("h1").text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on where the tag has been returned to you in the HTML response. For example, if the `<h1>` element is in the main body or standalone in the string without the surround html and body tags, then `find()` won't work for you. See this examnple:

```
var html_str = '<html><body><h1>Title</h1><h1>Second Title</h1></body></html>';
var html_str2 = '<h1>Title</h1><h1>Second Title</h1>';

$(html_str)       --> jQuery( h1, h1 )
$(html_str2)      --> jQuery( h1, h1 )
```

If you call find on these jQuery objects, then it will attempt to find the desired element from the children of the `<h1>` elements. This of course won't work. You can use filter to ensure that you only get the desired tag or just call `text()` directly, eg.

```
$(html_str).filter('h1').first().text()  --> 'Title'
$(html_str2).first().text()              --> 'Title'
```

If the `<h1>` is wrapped in a div, then it works fine. See:

```
var html_str3 = '<div><h1>Title</h1><h1>Second Title</h1></div>';

$(html_str3).find('h1')                     --> jQuery( h1, h1 )
$(html_str3).find('h1').first().text()      --> 'Title'
```

And lastly, remember to call `first()` as otherwise you will get the text from several `<h1>` elements concatenated together.

```
$(html_str3).find('h1').text()    --> 'TitleSecond Title'
```